# How can i move token from node to account in Corda

Tags: token, corda

I use Corda token sdk and Corda accounts.
(Corda_version = 4.1, tokens_version = 1.0 and accounts_version = 1.0-rc04)

I just built simple scenario:
Flow_1. PartyA-node create account "lisa"

```
start CreateAccount name: "lisa"
```

Flow_2. PartA-node issue Token to self

```
Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);
MyEvolvableToken myEvolvableToken = new MyEvolvableToken(...);
TransactionState<MyEvolvableToken> transactionState = new TransactionState<>(myEvolvableToken, notary);
subFlow(new CreateEvolvableTokens(myEvolvableToken));
・
・
・
//issue token to self
FungibleToken fungibleToken = new FungibleToken(amount, partya,TransactionUtilitiesKt.getAttachmentIdForGenericParam(tokenPointer))
return subFlow(new IssueTokens(ImmutableList.of(fungibleToken)));
```

Flow_3. PartA-node move Token to "lisa"

```
//Get Token from db
MyEvolvableToken token = stateAndRef.getState().getData();
TokenPointer tokenPointer = token.toPointer(token.getClass());
//Get Account from db
stateAndRefAccount = subFlow(new AccountInfoByName("lisa")).get(0);
AccountInfo lisaAccount = stateAndRefAccount.getState().getData();
//fresh account publicKey
PublicKey key = getServiceHub().getKeyManagementService().freshKey(lisaAccount.getIdentifier().getId()); 
AnonymousParty lisaParty = new AnonyMousParty(key);
//specify amount token to transfer
Amount<TokenPointer> amount = new Amount(10,tokenPointer);
PartyAndAmount partyAndAmount = new PartyAndAmount(lisaParty,amount);
return subFlow(new MoveFungibleTokens(partyAndAmount));
```

But,there is an error when i start Flow_3.
AnonymousParty dosen't work ??
How can i transfer token from node to account?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Called flow with anonymous party that node doesn't know about.Make sure that RequestConfidentialIdentity flow is called before.
.
.
at com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.workflows.flows.rpc.MoveFungibleTokens.call(MoveTokens.kt:22)
・
・
```

Comment: Very weird, I do the exact same steps in my flow and it works for me. I recommend that you add breakpoints and debug your flow, make sure you are not getting a null value at one of your lines.

Comment: On a side note you create an amount with `new Amount(10, tokenPointer);`, I don't know how many decimal points you have in your token type but if it's 100, then with that code you are creating `0.1` of your token not `10`. I recommend using `AmountUtilitiesKt.amount(10, tokenPointer)`; this will actually create a token with quantity `10`.

Comment: Also is this a typo? `new AnonyMousParty(key);` (instead of `AnonymousParty(key)`?)

Comment: @AdelRustum I change Corda_version 4.1 to 4.3, then  it work.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to our latest sample on Account + Token integration: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Accounts/worldcupticketbooking

To answer your question of how to issue token from node to account, you can issue the token directly to the anonymous party of the Account

For example:

```
//mention the current holder which is now going to be the dealer account 
NonFungibleToken nonFungibleToken = new NonFungibleToken(issuedTokenType, dealerAccount, new UniqueIdentifier(),TransactionUtilitiesKt.getAttachmentIdForGenericParam(tokenPointer)); 

//call built in flow to issue non fungible tokens 
SignedTransaction stx =  subFlow(new IssueTokens(Arrays.asList(nonFungibleToken)));
```

Where `dealerAccount` is an AnonymousParty.